# Задать задержку на стороне сервера при подключении по SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Server Ubuntu 16.04.

Перебирают root-пароли пытаясь зайти на сервер удаленно по SSH. fail2ban + iptables пресекают такие попытки. При задании времени блокировки IP-адреса злоумышленников в 24 часа, в цепочке fail2ban файрвола наблюдаю порядка 1500 заблокированных IP-шников.

Все вроде бы хорошо, но... При подключении к SSH и попытки ввода пароля нет никакой задержки. В логах fail2ban наблюдаю (смотрите время):

```
2019-11-15 08:28:14,086 fail2ban.filter         [964]: INFO    [ssh-iptables] Found 123.123.123.123
2019-11-15 08:28:14,087 fail2ban.filter         [964]: INFO    [ssh-iptables] Found 123.123.123.123
2019-11-15 08:28:14,088 fail2ban.filter         [964]: INFO    [ssh-iptables] Found 123.123.123.123
```

Получается, что за секунду можно перебрать около 1000 вариантов паролей. И это только с одного IP, при неработающем iptables или fail2ban. А такие случаи, что последние два падали без объяснения причин были.

Поэтому на ум приходит идея: а что если при подключении по SSH и вводе пароля на стороне сервера задать секундную задержку? Это возможно?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105559

Comment: Логин из-под рута у вас еще не запрещен? А порт ssh поменяли с дефолтного?

Comment: есть ли смысл менять порт ssh, если могут просканировать порты?

Comment: Сканировать ваши порты будут только при целенаправленной атаке на вас. Обычно сканируют адреса на дефолтном порту. Так что смена порта имеет смысл

Comment: @Alexey Ten, посоветуйте, как проще и надежнее это сделать? (сменить стандартные порты)

Comment: @Ruport сменить порт? Одна строчка в настройках sshd